# Meaning of conditional residence in 1871 baptismal record in Kilkenny, Ireland?

Tags: 19th-century, baptism-records, ireland, catholic-church

[image: Slieverue Catholic Parish Register 1871]

In Catholic Parish baptism register entry for Slieverue, Kilkenny in 1871, the place of residence for parents say "Ballinamona (conditional).

What is the meaning of conditional residence?

Answer (score 3):

Even though `(Conditional)` is written in the Residence column, I suspect that it is the baptism which is `Conditional` rather than the residence because the [Wikipedia entry for Conditional baptism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_baptism) says:

> Mainline Christian theology (including Roman Catholic, Eastern
>   Orthodox, Oriental Orthodox, Church of the East, Anglican, Lutheran
>   and most other Protestants) has traditionally held that only one
>   baptism is valid to confer the benefits of this sacrament. In
>   particular, the Council of Trent defined a dogma that it is forbidden
>   to baptize a person who is already baptized, because the first baptism
>   would make an indelible mark on the soul.
>
> ...
>
> Therefore, in cases where the validity of a baptism is in doubt, a
>   "conditional" baptism may be performed.

In other words, in your case, there seems to be some doubt about whether the person being baptised had been baptised previously, so this is a "just in case they hadn't been already" baptism.